# Как попасть на контроллер?

Tags: роутинг, .htaccess, php

Опишу суть проблемы:

на странице `index.php` есть ссылки на *категории* и страницу *`/feedback`*

```
<a href="/football">Football</a>
<a href="/volleyball">Volleyball</a>
<a href="/hockey">Hockey</a>

<p>
    <a href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
</p>
```

Правило `.htaccess` гласит

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^/feedback$ /feedback/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ category.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Из этого следует что если мы перейдем по url: `/football` мы попадем на контроллер `category.php`

```
// controller category

echo "This is a Category: <br />";

if (isset($_GET['category']) and !empty($_GET['category']))
{
    echo $_GET['category'];
}
```

Я специально закомментил правило с ссылкой на `/feedback`, потому что нажав на эту ссылку мы и так попадем куда надо, а именно на страницу `/feedback/index.php`:

```
<h1>FeedBack</h1>
```

Но выбрав категории сервер выдает данное сообщение:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /football was not found on this server.
```

Что не так?

Comment: сделайте роутер и не мучайтесь 

ошибка здесь:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$

Comment: А так я тупо сразу на этот контроллер попадаю, и мне на главной странице выводится: `This is a Category: 
category.php`

Comment: а ну поставте перед этой строкой 

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: О да! Теперь все в порядке!